# Passport auth in express backend using React Native/Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, passport.js, expo

I've been working on a companion app in React Native/Expo for a MERN web app that I created. In the back end, I have an Express server with Passport to authenticate users to Spotify as part of the sign in process, bound to the route `/auth/spotify`. On my web app, if I click the login button I'm redirected to the Spotify auth page. However, I can't seem to get it to work on React Native. Currently I'm using `axios` to send a GET request to `/auth/spotify` but it's seemingly not doing anything. I've checked the logs and the auth route is returning a 302 status, but the `/callback` url is never accessed. In the callback I have a `console.log` plus some code that accesses the database, but I've confirmed that neither of them are run when trying to auth from React Native.

I looked for tutorials but a lot of the stuff I found was outdated or used deprecated packages, so I'm kind of lost right now. Would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: have you found a solution? i am facing a similar problem which I think you can help me

Comment: @SangTonsing sorry I just saw this, are you still struggling with this?

Comment: Hi @jwoff I facing some issue kind of related to this, this is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088049/react-native-only-allow-passportjs-authenticated-users-to-access-api

Comment: Did you find a solution? I assume you have something that redirect in the web app (via embedded WebView to the auth) and then it redirects back to your app (which then takes the auth code and gets a access/refresh token and stores it in app's asyncStorage... Then it can authenticate with your express api (which uses passport for auth). 
With RN tooling:
https://laramo.medium.com/oauth-with-facebook-and-google-for-reactnative-using-passport-js-ffe0e63f86cb
WIth Expo tooling:
https://medium.com/@reneortega2468/log-in-with-google-in-react-native-using-oauth-2-0-protocol-with-expo-4ffb6c0123d1